# Error when I am installing TensorFlow Federated Learning. (error: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib')

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to install tensorflow federated using command: pip install tensorflow_federated
The installation completes successfuly, but when I am import the package using command
import tensorflow_federated as tff
I get below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/**init**.py", line 25, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python import *
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/**init**.py", line 25, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python.core import *
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/**init**.py", line 21, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python.core import utils
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/utils/**init**.py", line 26, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python.core.utils.computation_utils import IterativeProcess
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/utils/computation_utils.py", line 21, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python.core import api as tff
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/api/**init**.py", line 22, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python.core.api.computation_types import FederatedType
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/api/computation_types.py", line 26, in 
from tensorflow_federated.python.common_libs import anonymous_tuple
File "/home/dgholam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/common_libs/anonymous_tuple.py", line 28, in 
nest = tf.contrib.framework.nest
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

I will appreciate to you, if you can help me with this issue.
Python: 3.10.2
tensorflow-federated  0.1.0
tensorflow  2.11.0

I tried to install it with python 3.9.2 and 3.9.7 but I got another errors during installation. It seems tensorflow-federated needs tensorflow 2 and in tensorflow 2 there no contrib anymore. (contrib belongs to tensforlow 1.x.x)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install the oldest version of **TensorFlow Federated** (`TF Federated 0.1.0`, [released](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-federated/0.1.0/) on `Feb 23, 2019`)in the latest release of **Python version 3.10 or 3.9** which is causing the above error.

Please use the below command to upgrade the TensorFlow Federated version :

```
!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
```

and then import TensorFlow Federated as below:

```
import tensorflow_federated as tff
print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')())
print(tff.__version__)
```

Output:

```
b'Hello, World!'
0.56.0
```

Comment: Hi @Davoud Gholamian, Could you please accept the answer if it worked for you? Thank you.